# Adding a caption to an equation in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'd like to add a caption to a LaTeX-formatted equation, using org-mode's build-in `#+caption:` directive. [The manual says this is possible](https://orgmode.org/manual/Captions.html), but does not specify exactly how to format it. The most intuitive methods do not work; I tried all of the following:

```
#+caption: Kepler's third law
[\ T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M_1+M_2)} \]
```

```
#+caption: Kepler's third law
#+latex: \[ T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M_1+M_2)} \]
```

```
#+caption: Kepler's third law
\begin{equation}
T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M_1+M_2)}
\end{equation}
```

All three of these formattings result in the equation being rendered, but not the caption. I know it is possible to insert captions directly using LaTeX, but I would like to use the org native method, which the manual says I can do. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want such a behaviour? It looks quite strange to me. However, assuming you want to succeed with that solution, I'd change `equation` to `equation*` to avoid showing the equation number.

Comment: @exilsteira The document I'm writing warrants captioned, enumerated equations, and I prefer doing things natively in org when possible rather than hand-writing latex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to guess-and-check my way to finding an answer to this!

The trick is to wrap the equation in a figure:

```
#+caption: Kepler's third law
#+begin_figure
\begin{equation}
T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M_1+M_2)} R^3
\end{equation}
#+end_figure
```

This applied the caption correctly.

For posterity's sake, if you want to pass position options to the figure using this method, you need to use `:options []` instead of `:placement []`. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: Note: The caption does not show in HTML.